# ssh in bash script exits loop

Tags: bash, ssh, stdin

I am trying to run some commands on few remote hosts. I have the list of their ips in a file `ips.txt` (one ip per line).

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r wip; do
    echo $wip
    ssh root@$wip "pkill pgm; cd /root/pgm; nohup ./pgm  > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
    echo "$wip end"
done < ips.txt
```

I am running the above script. But the problem is after reading the first ip the loop exits. But if i remove the ssh line, it prints all ips.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ssh` reads everything from stdin (ips.txt).

Replace

```
ssh
```

with

```
ssh -n
```

---

See: `man ssh`